Kernel of a derivation over an arbitrary ring
Let $ D: R \to R$ be a mapping from a ring $R$ into itself which is a derivation (i.e. linear with respect to addition operation so that $D(x + y) = D(x) + D(y)$ and satisfies  Leibnitz's law: $D(xy) = xD(y) + yD(x)$).
Is it necessarily the case that $D(0) = 0$?
I'd like to use this fact to then prove that the "$\ker D$" (i.e. all elements $ x \in R$ such that $D(x) = 0$) is infact a subring and if the ring $R$ has an identity element it is necessarily in $\ker D$.
Specifically, is it correct to say that:
$$ D(0) = D(0*0) = 0D(0) + 0D(0) = 0 $$
Whence I can easily show that $D(-b) = D(0-b) = -D(b)$ and go from there for proving $\ker D$ is a subring?

Yes, your reasoning is sound: $ D ( 0 ) = 0 $ for the reason you say.  Alternatively, you can use the additive property and the existence of additive inverses (actually it's enough that addition is cancellative): $ D ( 0 ) = D ( 0 + 0 ) = D ( 0 ) + D ( 0 ) $, so (upon subtracting $ D ( 0 ) $) it follows that $ 0 = D ( 0 ) $.

If it's "linear with respect to addition", it's at least an abelian group homomorphism, hence $D(0)=0$ and in fact $\ker D$ is an additive subgroup. And if $D(x)=D(y)=0$, surely $D(xy) = xD(y)+yD(x)=0$, and if $R$ has $1_R$, we do have $D(1_R)=D(1_R^2)=1_RD(1_R)+1_RD(1_R)$ hence $D(1_R)=0$. Therefore $\ker D$ is indeed a (unital) subring, and $D$ is a homomorphism of $R$ as $\ker D$-modules.
